# Is Nautilus same as Files on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, files

14.04 fully updated on notebook and desktop.  But Nautilus on notebook and Files on desktop.  Why and can I install same on both?

Unity on both.  Files on desktop does not show free space as Nautilus does on note book.  And Files still sometime greys out copy etc options, as in previously reported bugs, for no apparent reason.

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Nautilus should appear as "Files" (or an equivalent in your language), and they *are* the same, unless you changed the default file manager . Hard to say why it appears as "Nautilus".  Did you change anything in the `.desktop` file?

Comment: And you installed Ubuntu on both? "14.04" could be anything

Comment: btw, are you using Unity on both?

Answer (score 1):

*Unless you've changed the default file manager in your Ubuntu:*

**Files** or **File Manager** are terms that are more easily understood by new users then the actual package name of **nautilus**.

For that you find this new naming but in deed they are both same.

Files is nautilus.

To get sure of what I'm talking about open your terminal and run the command nautilus from your desktop Pc. You'll notice that **Files** will open which means they are same.

You can think of Files as an alias for nautilus

Comment: Unless you changed the default file manager :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm yes sure